# hreflang tags not visible on google console even tho I put them on page. Why?

Tags: google-search-console, hreflang

I made my website on english language. It has now 1 language en and added the hreflang attributes.

There is no sitemap just the hreflang tags in html.

Most of the online tools see them but Google does not see them - it says in console - "Your site has no hreflang tags."

[Website Link](https://www.groupsfor.com/)

I added hreflangs on all pages.

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks,

John. V

Comment: try adding 'en-GB' instead: `<link href='https://www.groupsfor.com/' hreflang='en-GB' rel='alternate'/>`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.